# User Creation is getting duplicate emails in authentication by using Firebase admin api(node js)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

[image]

**API Used**:

```
admin.auth().createUser({
    email: user.email,
    emailVerified: false,
    password: creatPass(user.email),
    disabled: false,
})
```

Find the error in screenshot.

Comment: Is the issue still happening? I think it's already fixed based on your code above.

Comment: yeah, fixed Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for bringing this up - this is a known bug we are working on resolving and the fix will be coming out in an upcoming release.

Comment: This is a huge issue for my app - if a duplicate email got through, I'd have some significant tech support cost. I'm disappointed that this is still a problem almost 2 months later.

Comment: You must be calling createUser multiple times in parallel with the same email. Please remove that duplicate call.

Comment: @19Craig Do you call createUser with specified uid? If so, the issue is still pending fixed. But if you call createUser without uid, the issue should have already been fixed. Could you point out how you use createUser API?

Comment: <foot in mouth> I realized this morning that I'm chasing the wrong bug. My results are the same (duplicate emails saved in firebase account), but I'm having the problem with updateUser not createUser. Not enough coffee before posting last time. I've logged an incident in firebase for the my actual problem.

Comment: The problem with duplicate emails with updateUser is fixed in firebase-admin v4.1.1 released 2/14/17. Release notes indicate the same issue with createUser in this question is also fixed.